SQL Server 2022 trace flags
I have installed a SQL Server 2022 Developer Edition on an EC2 instance with Windows Server 2022 and installed the latest cumulative update (16.0.4115.5).
When I run DBCC TRACESTATUS there are 39 Global Trace Flags turned on and I have not been able to find information on any of them anywhere, e.g. 4511.
There are no trace flags as startup parameters.
At installation I choose Fulltext indexes and Polybase as extra features.
If I turn off all the trace flags and restart the server then they are turned back on automatically.
What are these trace flags? Part of cumulative update? Why can I not find any information on any of them?


I have installed a SQL Server 2022 Developer Edition on an EC2 instance


When I run DBCC TRACESTATUS there are 39 Global Trace Flags turned on


What are these trace flags? Part of cumulative update?

You'll have to ask either Amazon or Microsoft, whether or not they'll tell you is up to the fates.
You're utilizing Amazon's services, there are probably some reasons that those are enabled. Microsoft may provide trace flags to change behaviors that are more relevant to hosting providers and may require other integrations.

Why can I not find any information on any of them?

Microsoft does not publish a full list of trace flags and their usage, however some are published.

So SQL setup will check and if host is EC2 then it will enable extra trace flags?

@xhr489  It sounds very strange to me. We have 2019 on EC2 and the only trace flag that DBCC TRACESTATUS shows is 1222, and it was ME to enable it as I want deadlock graphs to be written to errorlog

@xhr489 Do you see these flags in the Configuration Manager as startup parameters?

@sepupic: No there are no TF as startup parameters.

@xhr489 You can check for it in errorlog: exec xp_readerrorlog 0,1,N'dbcc traceon' at least you'll see WHEN they were enabled. Then you can think what program did that

No, SQL Setup has nothing to do with it. Amazon is free to run their own integration via their hypervisor and any additional 3rd party software they'd like. You signed the agreement.

For example, Azure has the SQL IaaS Extension which will do many of these same things. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-server-iaas-agent-extension-automate-management?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#feature-benefits

@sepupic: No there are no DBCC TRACEON in errorlog. As mentioned in the question if I turn them off and restart the database engine then they are turned on again.

@SeanGallardy: How can Amazon turn on a Trace flag without there being a DBCC TRACEON in the errorlog?

You're assuming there is no other way to turn them on. There may or may not be other ways which are available to service providers @xhr489

Why does @sepupic not have extra trace flags on his EC2 instance?

@xhr489 My guess is you are using RDS, it's a limited and modified instance of SQL Server, we have one RDS and DBCC TRACESTATUS shows me 3226,7806,8017 flags that are not registered in errorlog (sure they modified also what is written to errorlog), the other instance is complete VM on EC2, not RDS, and there I see only what I'm turned on

@sepupic: I am not using RDS, but EC2 (this is also mentioned in the question)
